# Storing (copying) a row to be pasted into many sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the headers (row 1 and 3 of Sheet 1) into an object so they can be pasted into each new sheet I create.

I'm trying to do that with **header1** and **header2**. I don't know which of a dozen ways to specify a target I'm supposed to use.

```
Sub SplitIntoSheets()

' Steps to prep sheet:
'    Ensure there are exactly 3 header rows (code will ignore first three rows)
'    sort data by Provider (must filter out blank lines)
'    Replace all 'Dr. ' with '' in column C (sheet names cannot have punctuation)


Dim MyCell As Range, fromRange As Range, header1 As Range, header2 As Range
Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set wsFrom = ActiveSheet
Set MyRange = wsFrom.Range("C3:C2000")

Set header1 = wsFrom.Rows(1)
Set header2 = wsFrom.Rows(3)


For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
        MyCell.Value = shrinkNames(MyCell.Value)
    End If
Next MyCell


For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If Len(MyCell) > 0 Then
        If Not sheetExist(MyCell.Value) Then
            Set wsTo = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'creates a new worksheet
            wsTo.Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
            wsTo.Paste = header1
            wsTo.Paste = header2
            lastrow = 3
        Else
            Set wsTo = Worksheets(MyCell.Value)
            lastrow = wsTo.Cells(wsTo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
        
        wsFrom.Rows(MyCell.Row).Copy wsTo.Range("A" & lastrow)
                
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub

Function sheetExist(sSheet As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetExist = (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheet).Index > 0)
End Function

Function shrinkNames(sName As String) As String
    shrinkNames = Replace(sName, "Dr. ", "")
    
End Function
```

Comment: `header1.Copy  wsTo.Range("A1")` for example

Comment: `header1.Copy wsTo.Range("A1"): header2.Copy wsTo.Range("A3"): lastrow = 4` , The `lastRow` in`wsTo.Range("A" & lastrow)` is the first blank row, so it should be `4` after coping headers ( row 1 and 3 ).

Comment: You're kidding me. So, if I want to *paste* an object that I've *already copied* the keyword I use is *Copy*.

Comment: `Set header1 = wsFrom.Rows(1)` doesn't mean `Copy`. Try the code, you'll see the expected result.

Comment: For faster  operation you can place the respective headers in two arrays and drop their content in each sheet you need. But in this way, the header format will not be copied. You can do it in a second step using Copy - 1PasteSpecia xlPasteFormats1 and/or `xlPasteColumnWidths`.

Comment: `Set header1 = wsFrom.Rows(1)` just assigns `header1` as a *reference* to that row.  It doesn't perform any other action.  It does let you use `header1` in place of `wsFrom.Rows(1)` in the following code.